# Do schools save your search history on their computers they issue out?

Tags: wifi, spyware

So I received a laptop from the school and I was wondering if your logged into your own home network but signed into the computer (not in like a google account but like when your first turn on the computer you got to enter the username and password however the login for the computer is universal meaning to say it’s the same log in for all the students) if they could still receive the search history on the computer even if you were on a home network but logged into the computer with the universal login without physically having the computer in their possession and if so is it stored somewhere so they can go back and look at it? If you know the answer please let me know covid has gotten me going a little bit nuts

Comment: If it's running their software then they can do whatever they want with it, like logging keystrokes, screen captures, basically anything. You'd need to look at what's running and what kind of traffic it's sending out to determine whether or not it's actually collecting and sending it (no traffic doesn't rule out the possibility that the data could be stored and gathered later).

Comment: If you live in the European Union you might ask them if they have a privacy policy. I think the GDPR (an EU law) requires them to state what they do exactly with any personal data that might be processed using your laptop. However there's always the chance they could lie (and collect data without consent) or the chance that the machine has been infected by a third party (for example the technician who set up the laptops). I suggest you are careful about what you do on that laptop, so don't pull out your peepee in front of the webcam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it technically possible? Yes, of course. Is it legal? Probably, but depends on jurisdiction and exact scenario. Are they actually doing it? There is no reasonable way to know for sure unless they tell you.

Comment: They use a spyware called Impero Client